# How to give line break in animation using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to achieve type writer animation for give line spaces between I am using

```
function splitLetters(word) {
  var content = word.innerHTML;
  word.innerHTML ='';
  var letters = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    var letter = document.createElement('span');
    letter.className = 'letter';
    var char = content.charAt(i);
    letter.innerHTML = char===" "?"&nbsp;":char;
    word.appendChild(letter);
    letters.push(letter);
  }

  wordArray.push(letters);
}
```

> letter.innerHTML = char===" "?" ":char;

In the same way I want to give line break instead of `&nbsp` and possible way for that ?

Lets say suppose I want to display a line like

> great web developer

Now I want it to be displayed in this format

```
great web
developer
```

space between great and web and line break before developer.

Any help will be appreciated.
Also I don't want words to be spitted like wonderful into two words.

```js
var words = document.getElementsByClassName('word');
var wordArray = [];
var currentWord = 0;


for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  splitLetters(words[i]);
}

function changeWord() {
  var cw = wordArray[currentWord];
  var nw = currentWord == words.length-1 ? wordArray[0] : wordArray[currentWord+1];
  for (var i = 0; i < cw.length; i++) {
    animateLetterOut(cw, i);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < nw.length; i++) {
    nw[i].className = 'letter behind';
    nw[0].parentElement.style.opacity = 1;
    animateLetterIn(nw, i);
  }

  currentWord = (currentWord == wordArray.length-1) ? 0 : currentWord+1;
}

function animateLetterOut(cw, i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
  cw[i].className = 'letter out';
  }, i*80);
}

function animateLetterIn(nw, i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
  nw[i].className = 'letter in';
  }, 340+(i*80));
}

function splitLetters(word) {
  var content = word.innerHTML;
  word.innerHTML ='';
  var letters = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    var letter = document.createElement('span');
    letter.className = 'letter';
    var char = content.charAt(i);
    letter.innerHTML = char===" "?"&nbsp;":char;
    word.appendChild(letter);
    letters.push(letter);
  }

  wordArray.push(letters);
}

changeWord();
setInterval(changeWord, 4000);
```

```css
:root {
  --mainColor: #fff;
}

body{
  background-color: #252627;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.page{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.bglogo{
  position: absolute;
  top:20%;
  right: 15vh;
  height: 65vh;
  width: 65vh;
  z-index: 0;
}


path {
  fill: #252627;
  stroke: #00ffdc;
  animation: my_animation 2s linear forwards, filling .2s linear 2s forwards;
  stroke-dasharray: 400; /* need to ... */
  stroke-dashoffset: 400; /* ... match */
}

@keyframes my_animation {
  to {stroke-dashoffset: 0}
}

@keyframes filling {
  to {fill: #ff0046}
}

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600);

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 40%;
  max-height: 90%;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 64px;
}


.word {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.letter {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  transform: translateZ(25px);
  transform-origin: 50% 50% 25px;
}

.letter.out {
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
  transition: transform 0.32s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);
}

.letter.behind {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
}

.letter.in {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
  transition: transform 0.38s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}

.wisteria {
  color: #8e44ad;
}

.belize {
  color: #2980b9;
}

.pomegranate {
  color: #c0392b;
}

.green {
  color: #16a085;
}

.midnight {
  color: #2c3e50;
}


p {
  color: var(--mainColor);
  text-decoration: none;
}

p:hover {
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px var(--mainColor);
}

@supports not(-webkit-text-stroke: 2px red) {
  p:hover {
    text-shadow:
      3px 3px 0 var(--mainColor),
      -1px -1px 0 var(--mainColor),
      1px -1px 0 var(--mainColor),
      -1px 1px 0 var(--mainColor),
      1px 1px 0 var(--mainColor);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Vivank Sharma</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master_responsive.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </head>
  <body>


    <div class="page">
      <div class="bglogo">
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
      <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 18.1.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 89.999 89.999" style="enable-background:new 0 0 89.999 89.999;" xml:space="preserve">
        <g>
          <path d="M89.551,24.201c-5.029,28.863-33.127,53.301-41.577,58.883c-8.454,5.582-16.163-2.236-18.96-8.148   c-3.201-6.738-12.793-43.285-15.307-46.311C11.195,25.596,3.656,31.65,3.656,31.65L0,26.768c0,0,15.307-18.623,26.957-20.951   c12.35-2.469,12.332,19.318,15.301,31.416c2.873,11.701,4.807,18.398,7.312,18.398c2.514,0,7.311-6.525,12.562-16.531   c5.264-10.016-0.225-18.857-10.505-12.568C55.738,1.395,94.578-4.65,89.551,24.201z" fill="#ff0043"/>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </div>

    <div class="text">

      
      
      <p>
        <span class="word wisteria">wonderful developer</span>
        <span class="word belize">a great web devloper</span>
        
      </p>
      <p id="demo2"><p>


    </div>


  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/typewriter.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is to insert a `<br>` tag instead of `span`. you can do it for all the spaces like below:

```js
var words = document.getElementsByClassName('word');
var wordArray = [];
var currentWord = 0;


for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  splitLetters(words[i]);
}

function changeWord() {
  var cw = wordArray[currentWord];
  var nw = currentWord == words.length-1 ? wordArray[0] : wordArray[currentWord+1];
  for (var i = 0; i < cw.length; i++) {
    animateLetterOut(cw, i);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < nw.length; i++) {
    nw[i].className = 'letter behind';
    nw[0].parentElement.style.opacity = 1;
    animateLetterIn(nw, i);
  }

  currentWord = (currentWord == wordArray.length-1) ? 0 : currentWord+1;
}

function animateLetterOut(cw, i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
  cw[i].className = 'letter out';
  }, i*80);
}

function animateLetterIn(nw, i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
  nw[i].className = 'letter in';
  }, 340+(i*80));
}

function splitLetters(word) {
  var content = word.innerHTML;
  word.innerHTML ='';
  var letters = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    var letter = document.createElement('span');
    letter.className = 'letter';
    var char = content.charAt(i);
    if(char === " ")
        letter = document.createElement('br');
    else
        letter.innerHTML = char;
    word.appendChild(letter);
    letters.push(letter);
  }

  wordArray.push(letters);
}

changeWord();
setInterval(changeWord, 4000);
```

```css
:root {
  --mainColor: #fff;
}

body{
  background-color: #252627;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.page{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.bglogo{
  position: absolute;
  top:20%;
  right: 15vh;
  height: 65vh;
  width: 65vh;
  z-index: 0;
}


path {
  fill: #252627;
  stroke: #00ffdc;
  animation: my_animation 2s linear forwards, filling .2s linear 2s forwards;
  stroke-dasharray: 400; /* need to ... */
  stroke-dashoffset: 400; /* ... match */
}

@keyframes my_animation {
  to {stroke-dashoffset: 0}
}

@keyframes filling {
  to {fill: #ff0046}
}

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600);

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 40%;
  max-height: 90%;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 64px;
}


.word {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}


.letter:not(br) {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  transform: translateZ(25px);
  transform-origin: 50% 50% 25px;
}
br {
 clear:left;
}
.letter.out:not(br) {
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
  transition: transform 0.32s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);
}

.letter.behind:not(br) {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
}

.letter.in:not(br) {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
  transition: transform 0.38s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}

.wisteria {
  color: #8e44ad;
}

.belize {
  color: #2980b9;
}

.pomegranate {
  color: #c0392b;
}

.green {
  color: #16a085;
}

.midnight {
  color: #2c3e50;
}


p {
  color: var(--mainColor);
  text-decoration: none;
}

p:hover {
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px var(--mainColor);
}

@supports not(-webkit-text-stroke: 2px red) {
  p:hover {
    text-shadow:
      3px 3px 0 var(--mainColor),
      -1px -1px 0 var(--mainColor),
      1px -1px 0 var(--mainColor),
      -1px 1px 0 var(--mainColor),
      1px 1px 0 var(--mainColor);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Vivank Sharma</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master_responsive.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </head>
  <body>


    <div class="page">
      <div class="bglogo">
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
      <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 18.1.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 89.999 89.999" style="enable-background:new 0 0 89.999 89.999;" xml:space="preserve">
        <g>
          <path d="M89.551,24.201c-5.029,28.863-33.127,53.301-41.577,58.883c-8.454,5.582-16.163-2.236-18.96-8.148   c-3.201-6.738-12.793-43.285-15.307-46.311C11.195,25.596,3.656,31.65,3.656,31.65L0,26.768c0,0,15.307-18.623,26.957-20.951   c12.35-2.469,12.332,19.318,15.301,31.416c2.873,11.701,4.807,18.398,7.312,18.398c2.514,0,7.311-6.525,12.562-16.531   c5.264-10.016-0.225-18.857-10.505-12.568C55.738,1.395,94.578-4.65,89.551,24.201z" fill="#ff0043"/>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </div>

    <div class="text">

      
      
      <p>
        <span class="word wisteria">wonderful developer</span>
        <span class="word belize">a great web devloper</span>
        
      </p>
      <p id="demo2"><p>


    </div>


  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/typewriter.js"></script>
</html>
```

Or add a condition based on number of space or anything else:

```js
var words = document.getElementsByClassName('word');
var wordArray = [];
var currentWord = 0;
var spaces = 2;


for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
  splitLetters(words[i]);
}

function changeWord() {
  var cw = wordArray[currentWord];
  var nw = currentWord == words.length-1 ? wordArray[0] : wordArray[currentWord+1];
  for (var i = 0; i < cw.length; i++) {
    animateLetterOut(cw, i);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < nw.length; i++) {
    nw[i].className = 'letter behind';
    nw[0].parentElement.style.opacity = 1;
    animateLetterIn(nw, i);
  }

  currentWord = (currentWord == wordArray.length-1) ? 0 : currentWord+1;
}

function animateLetterOut(cw, i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
  cw[i].className = 'letter out';
  }, i*80);
}

function animateLetterIn(nw, i) {
  setTimeout(function() {
  nw[i].className = 'letter in';
  }, 340+(i*80));
}


function splitLetters(word) {
  var content = word.innerHTML;
  word.innerHTML ='';
  var letters = [];
  var space = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    var letter = document.createElement('span');
    letter.className = 'letter';
    var char = content.charAt(i);
    if(char === " ") {
        if(space == spaces)
            letter = document.createElement('br');
        else
            letter.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
        space++;       
    }
    else
        letter.innerHTML = char;
    word.appendChild(letter);
    letters.push(letter);
  }

  wordArray.push(letters);
}

changeWord();
setInterval(changeWord, 4000);
```

```css
:root {
  --mainColor: #fff;
}

body{
  background-color: #252627;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.page{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.bglogo{
  position: absolute;
  top:20%;
  right: 15vh;
  height: 65vh;
  width: 65vh;
  z-index: 0;
}


path {
  fill: #252627;
  stroke: #00ffdc;
  animation: my_animation 2s linear forwards, filling .2s linear 2s forwards;
  stroke-dasharray: 400; /* need to ... */
  stroke-dashoffset: 400; /* ... match */
}

@keyframes my_animation {
  to {stroke-dashoffset: 0}
}

@keyframes filling {
  to {fill: #ff0046}
}

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:600);

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.text {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 40%;
  max-height: 90%;
}

p {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 64px;
}


.word {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.letter:not(br) {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  transform: translateZ(25px);
  transform-origin: 50% 50% 25px;
}

br {
 clear:left;
}

.letter.out:not(br) {
  transform: rotateX(90deg);
  transition: transform 0.32s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);
}

.letter.behind:not(br) {
  transform: rotateX(-90deg);
}

.letter.in:not(br) {
  transform: rotateX(0deg);
  transition: transform 0.38s cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
}

.wisteria {
  color: #8e44ad;
}

.belize {
  color: #2980b9;
}

.pomegranate {
  color: #c0392b;
}

.green {
  color: #16a085;
}

.midnight {
  color: #2c3e50;
}


p {
  color: var(--mainColor);
  text-decoration: none;
}

p:hover {
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px var(--mainColor);
}

@supports not(-webkit-text-stroke: 2px red) {
  p:hover {
    text-shadow:
      3px 3px 0 var(--mainColor),
      -1px -1px 0 var(--mainColor),
      1px -1px 0 var(--mainColor),
      -1px 1px 0 var(--mainColor),
      1px 1px 0 var(--mainColor);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Vivank Sharma</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/master_responsive.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </head>
  <body>


    <div class="page">
      <div class="bglogo">
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
      <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 18.1.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 89.999 89.999" style="enable-background:new 0 0 89.999 89.999;" xml:space="preserve">
        <g>
          <path d="M89.551,24.201c-5.029,28.863-33.127,53.301-41.577,58.883c-8.454,5.582-16.163-2.236-18.96-8.148   c-3.201-6.738-12.793-43.285-15.307-46.311C11.195,25.596,3.656,31.65,3.656,31.65L0,26.768c0,0,15.307-18.623,26.957-20.951   c12.35-2.469,12.332,19.318,15.301,31.416c2.873,11.701,4.807,18.398,7.312,18.398c2.514,0,7.311-6.525,12.562-16.531   c5.264-10.016-0.225-18.857-10.505-12.568C55.738,1.395,94.578-4.65,89.551,24.201z" fill="#ff0043"/>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </div>

    <div class="text">

      
      
      <p>
        <span class="word wisteria">wonderful developer</span>
        <span class="word belize">a great web devloper</span>
        
      </p>
      <p id="demo2"><p>


    </div>


  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/typewriter.js"></script>
</html>
```

I also adjusted some of the CSS so the `br` won't get affected by the other classes

Comment: yeah but big words like `wonderful` is breaking can you fix that ?

Comment: @MansiShukla Any word will break because you split it to different spans so technically it's no more one word ... not sure if we can fix this with the current code

Comment: any help in this will be great if possible any ways thanks for he help

Comment: @MansiShukla I will try to think about a way ;)